# Issue with foreach routine adding variable to array

Tags: php, arrays

When calling the function below and passing the parameters "test/asdf" for `$url` and "variables" for `$element`, the `foreach` routine doesn't add the variable `$var` to the `$variables` array. However, the routine correctly prints out the `$var` value.

```
public function ParseURL($url, $element)
    {
        $splitURL = preg_split("/(\\/)/is", $url);
        if ($element == "page_id"){return $splitURL[0];}
        elseif ($element == "all"){return $splitURL;}
        elseif ($element == "variables"){
            $i = 1;
            $variables = array(0 => "test");
            foreach ($splitURL as $var) {
                if ($var != $splitURL[0]){
                    $variables[$i] == $var;
                    echo $var;
                    echo $variables[$i];
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            var_dump($variables);
            return $variables;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

The input URL would be everything after the domain of a webpage, so if you inputted the string `example.com/function/variable/variable2`, it would return either "function", an array containing "function", `variable` and `variable2` or an array containing "variable" and "variable" based on the string inputted into the element parameter.

The expected output is an array of `variable` and `variable2`.

Comment: What does the URL look like ? What is your expected output ... you need to add this details ....

Comment: Sorry, added it onto the question for future reference.

Comment: Just use `explode` and `parse_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the assignment, in your example, theres a double `==`:

```
$variables[$i] == $var;
               ^^
```

You probably wanted to write only one

Answer (score 0):

change `$variables[$i] == $var;` to `$variables[$i] = $var;`